# How to push a shadow to the backside of a sibling div

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

I am trying to push the shadow of the sibling div to the back of the div.
I went through the other questions related to this, but none of them worked for me.

I tried adding `position` and `z-index` but no luck so far. Here is the CSS I am using:

```css
#example1 {
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 12px 15px #888888;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="example1">
  <p>The optional third value adds a blur effect to the shadow.</p>
</div>

<div id="example1" >
  <p>More blurred.</p>
</div>

<div id="example1">
  <p>More blurred and red.</p>
</div>
```

The shadow should be behind the sibling div, but it is falling on top of the sibling div.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GDXWPF9J8FK5) is the live example.

[image: Shadows on top of sibling divs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some were before me, but to only place the second div op top make sure to only set the background color on that div:

```
.example1 {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.example1::before {
  box-shadow: 5px 12px 15px #888888;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.pushtop {
  background: white;
}
```

See jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sanderdebr/kj1b7mgv/16/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use the same ID on more than one element.

Second, give your divs a `background-color`.

That's it.

```css
.example {
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 12px 15px #888888;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="example1" class="example">
  <p>The optional third value adds a blur effect to the shadow.</p>
</div>

<div id="example2" class="example">
  <p>More blurred.</p>
</div>

<div id="example3" class="example">
  <p>More blurred and red.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this solve your issue?

```css
.example {
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 12px 15px #888888;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: white;
}


/**
.example1 {
  z-index: 1;
}

.example2 {
  z-index: 2;
}

.example3 {
  z-index: 3;
}
**/
```

```html
<div class="example example1">
  <p>The optional third value adds a blur effect to the shadow.</p>
</div>

<div class="example example2">
  <p>More blurred.</p>
</div>

<div class="example example3">
  <p>More blurred and red.</p>
</div>
```